# Myeclipse HTML 5 Mobile application build failed

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, myeclipse

I am using **MyeClipse 2013 Professional** to create Hybrid mobile application.

I created HTML5 mobile application for Android, but facing issue once i use **build mobile application** option from eclipse it throws an error shown in image below.

[image]

Let me know if anybody have any solution or fix.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 hybrid mobile app tools were replaced, in the 2015 release, by PhoneGap application tools. The App Center was retired early in 2015. MyEclipse licenses are time based so you can install and use the 2015 release under a valid license (and the CI stream gets frequent updates with new features and fixes). There is [a tutorial](https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/learning-center/mobile/html5-to-phonegap/) available which explains how to convert your hybrid apps to PhoneGap apps.